# Sum function producing whole number instead of percentage

Tags: sql-server-2008

So I have a field 'total' which is made of (fin_dec+fin_acc). I've been trying to divide total by fin acc:

```
 select sum(case when fin_acc = 0 then 0 else (total/fin_acc)end)as sum1
```

The case statement is because it won't divide by 0s!

For example, total is 4 and fin_acc is 3 therefore the sum should be 75% however it's just giving me 3. It could be how I've created the fin_dec, fin_acc fields as a case when... then 1 else 0 and therefore wont split into a percentage. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Pleas check your formulas. It seems that `total/fin_acc` where `total=4` and `fin_acc=3` never gives 75%, but 1 in case they are `INT` and 1.333333 in case they are `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the nullif function:

```
select sum(1.0*total/nullif(fin_acc,0))as sum1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
select sum(fin_acc) as s, count(fin_acc) as n from ..
```

then in your programming language:

```
if(n>0) avg= s/n else avg= null;
```

or just use:

```
select avg(fin_acc) as a from ..
```